# does this operation hold?

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

[image]

The answer tells me it does hold. But I just couldn't see it. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: There are clearly _multiple_ typos in in the question. Besides the fact that $x^n \oplus n^m$ should almost certainly be $x^n \otimes x^m$, as pointed out by Matthew Daly below, the symbol $\otimes$ seems to be omitted from several places: $1x$ should presumably be $1 \otimes x$, and $(n+1)x = nx \oplus x$ should be $(n \oplus 1) \otimes x = (n \otimes x) \oplus x$. What's the point of even defining the circled addition and multiplication operators if you're not going to use them consistently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't hold on $(\mathbb Z,+\times)$, right?! For instance $2^2+2^2\neq2^4$.

Answer (score 6):

As noted, there is clearly a typo in the problem; it should be $\otimes$ and not $\oplus$.  With that correction, the statement is true.

Let $n$ be given.  We will show that $x^n\otimes x^m=x^{n+m}$ for all positive integers $m$ by induction.

First, $x^n\otimes x^1=x^{n+1}$ by your definition of the exponentiation notation.

Now, assume $x^n\otimes x^k=x^{n+k}$ for some positive integer $k$.  Then

$$x^n\otimes x^{k+1}=x^n\otimes (x^k\otimes x)=(x^n\otimes x^k)\otimes x=x^{n+k}\otimes x=x^{n+(k+1)}$$ by the definition of the exponentiation, the associativity of $\otimes$, and the induction hypothesis.  Therefore, by the principle of mathematical induction, the statement holds for all values of $m$ (and therefore also $n$, since it was arbitrarily chosen at the beginning).